# Launching bash script from javascript issue

Tags: javascript, bash, plasmoid

I'm trying to launch bash script from javascript (plasmoid).
I have in plasmoid's main.js this command:

```
plasmoid.runCommand("bash-script.sh");
```

When starting plasmoid from terminal by plasmoidviewer, I can see all the output that I expecting to see.
But I want to redirect script's output to file. So I trying to do it like this:

```
plasmoid.runCommand("bash-script.sh > output.txt");
```

But output.txt does not appear.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work:

```
plasmoid.runCommand("bash",["-c","./contents/code/bash-script.sh >output.txt"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it that way:

```
plasmoid.runCommand("bash -c 'bash-script.sh > output.txt'");
```

'>' is a bash's operator to redirect output to file, and because that it should be passed to bash.

Comment: Unfortunately it does nothing. Still no output file.